# How to build compound conditions in bash for cycle

Tags: bash

I have following for cycle:

```
flag=true
for ((i = 0; (( i <= ${#array[@]} / 5 - 1 && "$flag" == true )); i++))
do
   flag=false
   echo "The loop continues."
done
```

My for loop continues even flag is set to false. It seems the rest of condition in for cycle "$flag" == true is not evaluated. How to fix the condition in for cycle to have canceled for loop cycle if flag is set to false?

Comment: Presumably both `true` and `false` and `asdfghjk` have a numeric value of `0`, and you're using numeric operators.

Comment: You could split the `"$flag" == true` part into a separate if condition and make the entire thing a `for + if ` construct. Also the `((..))` is for arithmetic context and may not be applicable for string comparisons

Comment: What is the value of `${#array[@]}`?

Answer (score 2):

> You can't use a C-style for construct for this …

That statement is *false*. The code as written in the question can be corrected just with melpomene's suggested change:

> You could also just use `1` and `0` instead of `true` and `false`,
>   respectively.

```
flag=1
for ((i = 0; (( i <= ${#array[@]} / 5 - 1 && "$flag" == 1 )); i++))
do
  flag=0
  echo "The loop continues."
done
```